# Pinch zoom for entire stage?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I have made an app for desktop in flash cc (as3). I tried creating an android version too from same. But when I tried in an android mobile with smaller screen size readability of the app texts are too low. I just want to add the pinch zoom gesture to zoom the portion of app and make it comfortable to read. Can someone suggest me an idea. Is there any way where I can zoom stage with all objects and contents? Eg: if user wants to zoom n read a test written he should be able to pinch and zoom and pan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS3 Pinch Zooming for use on android is easy.
for example to pinch scale an MC use something like.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom); 
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
  square_mc.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
  square_mc.scaleY *= e.scaleY; 
}
```

and for stage maybe something like

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom); 
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
  stage.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
  stage.scaleY *= e.scaleY; 
}
```